# Calling a Stored Procedure in a Stored Procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I can't find this answer anywhere, but can you call a Stored Procedure from another Stored Procedure in MySQL?  I want to get the Identity Value back and use it in the parent Stored Procedure.  We can't use FUNCTIONS anymore!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE innerproc(OUT param1 INT)
BEGIN
 insert into sometable;
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() into param1 ;
END
-----------------------------------
CREATE PROCEDURE outerproc()
BEGIN
CALL innerproc(@a);
// @a gives you the result of innerproc
SELECT @a INTO variableinouterproc FROM dual;
END
```

`OUT` parameters should help you in getting the values back to the calling procedure. Based on that the solution must be something like this.

Comment: You are using out, do you think this is better then doing LAST_INSERT_ID()?

Comment: If it were a function, you would return the LAST_INSERT_ID from the function as RETURN VALUE.This solution must provide the same so that the PROCEDURE is equivalent to the function

Comment: The other answer says I can use LAST_INSERT_ID() without OUT?

Comment: @Mike Flynn - Did you try my example yourself? You can call sp2 multiple times, and you'll get the next incremented id back each time. I know because I tested it :).

Comment: Not yet but I will and will mark your answer as correct after I do it probably today.

Answer (score 18):

To call another procedure, use [CALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html):
ex: `Call SP1(parm1, parm2);`

To get identity, did you try checking out [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id); You would do something like `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` after your SP call.

Here's a complete, tested example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) $$

CREATE PROCEDURE sp1()
BEGIN
  insert into animals (name) values ('bear');
END $$

CREATE PROCEDURE sp2()
BEGIN
  call sp1;
  select last_insert_id();
END $$

call sp2;
```

Comment: You are using LAST_INSERT_ID(), do you think this is better then doing out?

Comment: @Mike Flynn- OUT parameter isn't really needed, you can get the last inserted id by just calling select last_insert_id().

Comment: what if I want to return the LAST INSERTED ID, or retrieve it if its available in the same function?

Comment: @Mike Flynn - You can call select last_insert_id();
 multiple times, either within the SP where the insert was done, or elsewhere. If you want to return it, you could use a function, or an OUT parameter. Either way should work.