# Store Procedure Concat a select while in a loop

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm building a serie of Procedures where I'll have to insert generic names in almost all of them, and multiples columns.

So I thought in create a Procedure to Generate a "text" for me. The code for the text is this:

```
SELECT CONCAT( CHAR( FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25))));
```

This generates one random char for me. So this is the procedure that I made:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`my_definer`@`localhost` PROCEDURE GenericName(IN NumRows INT,OUT retorno VARCHAR)
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    SET i = 1;
    SET retorno = "";
    WHILE i <= NumRows DO
        SET retorno = SELECT CONCAT( CHAR( FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25))));
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

The following error is what is appearing when I try to create the procedure:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') BEGIN DECLARE i INT; SET i = 1; SET retorno = "";

Based on the error, I think is something stupid, but I don't have much of expertise in creating Store Procedures and I may be overthinking something.

---

PS (this is the future usage that I'm planing to do when I finish the procedure above): The idea is to call this procedure in other procedures by something like:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_a (name, position) VALUES (CALL GenericName(7), CALL GenericName(5));
```

External links:

- I saw that is possible to call a procedure from another procedure here "[Calling a Stored Procedure in a Stored Procedure in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000802/calling-a-stored-procedure-in-a-stored-procedure-in-mysql)"

Comment: Initially I was trying to do something like `SET retorno = CONCAT( retorno, SELECT CONCAT( CHAR( FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25)))) );` So I can create a complete string (with as many char as I want). But, I didn't even finish the above =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PROBLEM #1

You should not be using a Stored Procedure. You should be using a Stored Function

## PROBLEM #2

In the loop, you forgot to include `retorno` in the CONCAT

## PROBLEM #3

Also, I would change

```
CHAR(FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25)))
```

to

```
CHAR(FLOOR(65.5 + (RAND() * 25)))
```

to give the letter `Z` a fair chance to appear

## PROBLEM #4

Replace

```
SET retorno = SELECT CONCAT(...
```

with

```
SET retorno = CONCAT(...
```

## PROPOSED STORED FUNCTION

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`my_definer`@`localhost` FUNCTION GenericName
(NumRows INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE retorno VARCHAR(20);
    SET i = 1;
    SET retorno = "";
    WHILE i <= NumRows DO
        SET retorno = CONCAT(retorno,CHAR(FLOOR(65.5 + (RAND() * 25))));
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN retorno;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you can call the INSERT like this

```
INSERT INTO tbl_a (name, position) VALUES (GenericName(7),GenericName(5));
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Thanks for the adivise on the `function` instead of `procedure`. I'm getting the following error, with the code you posted: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CONCAT(retorno,CHAR( FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25))));
        SET i = i + 1;
' at line 11". The editor (sequelPro) highlight the follow part of the code: `SELECT CONCAT(retorno,CHAR( FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25))));
        SET i = i + 1;`

Comment: Thanks for the fast assistance. It says "No RETURN found in FUNCTION my_definer.GenericName", I added `return retorno;` after the `END WHILE;` and it worked (I tested by using `SELECT GenericName(7);`) PS: Thanks again for the help, I learn a **lot** from your answers, thanks for helping the community so much =)

Comment: Sorry I missed the RETURN. I just added it.