# Can't find where is the MySQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, macos, stored-procedures, terminal, procedure

```
delimiter %%
create procedure getFileID(in fname varchar(100), out fId int)
begin
    select ID from File
    where Name = fname
    into fId;
end %%
delimiter ;

delimiter $$
create procedure FileINFO(in fname varchar(100))
begin
    declare SMS_done, Par_don boolean default false;
    declare SMSID int;
    declare SMSName varchar(100) default "";
    declare SMSCode varchar(100) default "";
    declare ParamName varchar(100) default "";
    declare fId int default 0;
    call getFileID(fname, fId);
    declare c1 cursor for select ID, Code, Name from SMSTemplate where F_ID = fId;
    declare continue handler for not found set SMS_done = true;
    open c1;
    SMS_loop : loop
        fetch from c1 into SMSID, SMSCode, SMSName;
            if SMS_done then
                close c1;
                leave SMS_loop;
            end if;
        block2 : begin
        declare c2 cursor for 
            select Name from ParameterType where ST_ID = SMSID;
        declare continue handler for not found set Par_done = true;
        open c2;
        Par_loop : loop
            fetch from c2 into ParamName;
            if SMS_done then
            set SMS_done = false;
            close c2;
            leave Par_loop;
            end if;
        insert into FileDetails
        (FileName, SMSName, SMSCode, ParamName)
        values
        (fname, SMSName, SMSCode, ParamName);
        end loop Par_loop;
        end block2;
    end loop SMS_loop;
    select * from FileDetails;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

and i get that error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use 
near 'declare c1 cursor for select ID, Code, Name from SMSTemplate where F_ID = fId;' at line 10
```

Comment: OMG boy, please learn how to format a question appropriately. Please use the `{}` button in SO's editor next time.

Comment: A little googling gave me [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11000907/5830574). Perhaps it fits your needs? I think the `@` sign is the key for out params.

Comment: @PerlDog Sorry for this mistake. I fixed it. help please

Comment: Well, actually ***I*** fixed it, but never mind. I'm not familiar with calling SPs from other SPs but please have a look at my previous comment. (When getting a 1064, the error is almost always _before_ the `near '...'` stuff.)

Comment: @PerlDog I know that you fixed it i mean i approved the change. Don't be hard, I need help I don't ask for money so be cool. 2nd actually the link didn't help, but thanks

Comment: Sorry if you got me wrong. Didn't want to get rude or sth. Peace. Doesn't `call getFileID(fname, @fId);` work?

Comment: nvm, it works well alone so i really don't know where is my mistake

Comment: `DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.`, see [14.6.3 DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html). Also, declare the variable `Par_done`.

Comment: @wchiquito it works but now i need to call getFileID 1st because i want to use the out value in cursor c1 

so what to do? 

do you mean that i make new block ang make that declare inside it ?!

Comment: @PerlDog Thank you for your efforts :)

Comment: @wchiquito Thank you. I made it :)

Comment: Place the stored procedure call (`getFileID`) before opening the first cursor. Where you use the `Par_done` variable?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for starters get the declares all grouped together at the top.
Also there is no such thing as `fetch into` so those two things were fixed.

Par_don / Par_done had a typo in the declare.

Also, for sanity, have a drop if exist for the stored proc right above each one, so it is easily scripted and maintained.

```
drop procedure if exists FileINFO;
delimiter $$
create procedure FileINFO(in fname varchar(100))
begin
    declare SMS_done, Par_done boolean default false;
    declare SMSID int;
    declare SMSName varchar(100) default "";
    declare SMSCode varchar(100) default "";
    declare ParamName varchar(100) default "";
    declare fId int;
    declare c1 cursor for select ID, Code, Name from SMSTemplate where F_ID = fId;
    declare continue handler for not found set SMS_done = true;
    call getFileID(fname,  fId );



    open c1;

    SMS_loop : loop
        fetch c1 into SMSID, SMSCode, SMSName;
            if SMS_done then
                close c1;
                leave SMS_loop;
            end if;
        block2 : begin
        declare c2 cursor for 
            select Name from ParameterType where ST_ID = SMSID;
        declare continue handler for not found set Par_done = true;
        open c2;
        Par_loop : loop
            fetch from c2 into ParamName;
            if SMS_done then
            set SMS_done = false;
            close c2;
            leave Par_loop;
            end if;
        insert into FileDetails
        (FileName, SMSName, SMSCode, ParamName)
        values
        (fname, SMSName, SMSCode, ParamName);
        end loop Par_loop;
        end block2;
    end loop SMS_loop;
    select * from FileDetails;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Also, if you are new to mysql learn sets and relations and avoid cursors completely. Cursors are predominantly used by people who don't know sql and want to think procedural. They perform like dogs.

Comment: Thank you, but i need the value out from getFileDetails to use it with the 1st cursor :)

Answer (score 0):

Does the table `SMSTemplate` have a field `F_ID`??

If not, that could be why you're getting this error.