# Mysql Trigger Declare Before Loop

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

Alright guys, I couldn't find this anywhere but maybe I just don't know exactly how to look. I'm using a trigger that calls a procedure for each row, but I want to insert some DECLARE statements there before the FOR EACH ROW. The reason why is that I want to DECLARE a few things before the LOOP (for each row), so I don't end up declaring the same thing over and over again for each of the rows I have.

Anyone knows how to do that? Is it even possible?

Here how my trigger was looking like:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER tr_inscricao_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON tbl_inscricao

    DECLARE ra_current INT;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

FOR EACH row
BEGIN
    CALL pr_atualizar_creditos(new.ra);
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: `declare` should be after the `BEGIN` statement. And calling `Procedure` within trigger is not recommended. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

Comment: Yes, I know it should be after. I'm asking if there is anyway somehow to do it before...

Answer (score 0):

You can add another layer and call your stored procedure from a stored procedure which includes the declaration part and is called from your trigger.
See this thread for some inspiration:
[Calling a Stored Procedure in a Stored Procedure in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000802/calling-a-stored-procedure-in-a-stored-procedure-in-mysql)

Comment: I did not get exactly how this helps my problem. I want to make some DECLARE statements before FOR EACH ROW. I want this statements to happen only once per trigger, and not once for each row (as the rest of the trigger will happen).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have the necessary statement level triggers to achieve this in the standard way, however I created the following workaround. In the before trigger, before the first row, it checks if the ROW_COUNT is -1 which means no rows have been inserted yet and sets the default value 1 to @x. Then the @x can be used in the after update. In the before trigger, before the second row, when it checks the ROW_COUNT it is now 1, or higher if your after trigger inserted more rows, either way it is no longer -1 so the initialisation does not run again.

```
DROP TRIGGER record_before_update;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER record_before_update 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON record
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE y INT;
    SET y = (SELECT ROW_COUNT());
    IF y = -1 THEN 
        SET @x = 1;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DROP TRIGGER record_after_update;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER record_after_update 
    AFTER UPDATE ON record
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    #use @x in something
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Note that in your transaction the statement that uses the trigger will need to be called before any other updates otherwise ROW_COUNT won't be -1. And this example was for update, you'll need the same thing for the insert trigger.

In in case it helps to see a real example, here is how I am using it. When there is an update for a bunch of rows in different "zones", it only updates a single zone by maintaining an array of the zones already updated.

```
DROP TRIGGER record_before_update;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER record_before_update 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON record
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE y INT;
    SET y = (SELECT ROW_COUNT());
    IF y = -1 THEN 
        SET @x = NULL;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DROP TRIGGER record_after_update;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER record_after_update 
    AFTER UPDATE ON record
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM record_change where record_id = NEW.id;
    INSERT INTO record_change(record_id, number) VALUES(NEW.id, @x);
    IF @x IS NULL OR FIND_IN_SET(NEW.zone_id, @x) = 0 THEN
      SET @x = CONCAT_WS(',', @x, NEW.zone_id);
        DELETE FROM zone_change where zone_id = NEW.zone_id;
        INSERT INTO zone_change(zone_id, number) VALUES(NEW.zone_id, @x);       
    END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```